# If $p(T)(x) \in W$, then $p(T)q(T)(x)\in W$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T:V \to V$ and $W \leqslant V$, $T-$invariant. Let $x\in V$, $x\not \in W$

I have $h(t), p(t)$ such that $h(T)(x), p(T)(x) \in W$

If $h(t) = p(t) q(t) + r(t)$, I want to see that $r(T)(x) \in W$ but it not clear for me to see that $p(T)q(T)(x)\in W$. Furthermore, I want to use the $T-$invariance of $W$ to clearly see that the degree of $r(t)$ must be $0$.

I can't understand if I need to handle the expression $p(T)q(T)(x)\in W$ as it was a product of linear transformations or a composition of lineal transformations.

If I show that $p(T)q(T)(x)\in W$, since $h(T)(x) \in W$, $r(T)(x) = h(T)(x) - p(T)q(T)(x)\in W$, because $W$ is subvector space.

EDIT 1:

Maybe I missed that $p(t)$ is minimal polynomial of $T$. Thus, $p(T) = T_0$ and $p(T)(q(T)(x)) = T_0(q(T)(x)) = 0 \in W$. Is this correct?

EDIT 2:

I'm adding the problem to solve.

[image]

EDIT 3:

We can note that $h(T) = T_0$. If it wasn't true, $h(T)(x) = c_0 x + c_1 T(x) + c_2 T^2(x) + \cdots + c_m T^m(x) \in W$, but $x \not \in W \leqslant V$, which leads to a contradiction. Thus, $h(T) = T_0$. (Maybe I'm wrong). This means that $r(T) = T_0$, but $p(t)$ is minimal and degree of $r(t)$ is less than $p(t)$, so $r(t) = 0$.

Comment: deg$(r)$ can't be $0$. If it were, $r(T) = cI$ for some $c$, so that $r(T)(x) = cx \not \in W$.

Comment: @Vishu Shouldn't that imply that $r(t) = 0$? Thus $r(T)(x) = 0 I_v(x) = 0 \in W$?

Comment: Any constant polynomial has degree $0$.

Comment: @Vishu Of course, but we have three facts: 1) $p(t)$ is minimal, 2) degree of $r(t)$ is less than $p(t)$ by the Division Algorithm, and if $r(t) = c$ for $c \neq 0$ happens the contradiction you pointed. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @BlueTomato Which book is this?

Comment: @Seeker Fiedberg, 4rd edition, section 7.3.

Comment: @BlueTomato Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint. $T$ is suitably definable on $V/W$, i.e. as $\tilde T$, with
$$
\tilde T(x+W)=Tx+W
$$
Then the minimal polynomial of $\tilde T$ is the $g_1$.